# VBA iteration not returning value

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a very simple sub process to assign a letter grade to numeric grade values.  I have a loop and I am trying to set the cell value to the output of my function. This seems like a very simple task but the first two iterations of my loops are not assigning any values.  My Loop only goes through 4 rows.

```
Function get_letter(grade As Double)
    Select Case grade
        Case 0 To 59: letter = "F"
        Case 60 To 69: letter = "D"
        Case 70 To 79: letter = "C"
        Case 80 To 89: letter = "B"
        Case 90 To 100: letter = "A"
    End Select
    get_letter = letter
End Function

Sub assign_letter_grade()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim grade As Range
    Dim letter As Range

    num_rows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    Set grade = Range("J2")
    Set letter = Range("K2")

    For x = 1 To num_rows
        letter.Value = get_letter(grade.Value)
        Set grade = grade.Offset(1, 0)
        Set letter = letter.Offset(1, 0)
    Next
End Sub
```

Why don't this set the values of my first two rows in the loop?

Comment: What happens when you put `=get_letter(J2)` in K2 and fill down? Could the values in column J be text masquerading as numbers?

Comment: The value of J2 is a calculation -  =IF(SUM(C2:F2)/400*0.2*100+MAX(G2:H2)/100*0.8*100>100, 100, SUM(C2:F2)/400*0.2*100+MAX(G2:H2)/100*0.8*100)

Comment: Just to be sure I casted the value using CDbl and still the same results

Comment: OT a bit - that formula might be better as =MIN(100, SUM(C2:F2)/400*0.2*100+MAX(G2:H2)/100*0.8*100))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Function get_letter(grade As Double) As String
    if grade < 60 Then
        get_letter = "F"
    Elseif grade < 70 Then
        get_letter = "D"
    Elseif grade < 80 Then
        get_letter = "C"
    Elseif grade < 90 Then
        get_letter = "B"
    Else
        get_letter = "A"
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the scores that is NOT included in the range.  For VBA a score of 79.25 does not falls in either Case C or B.  You could try to see if below would fix the problem:

```
Function get_letter(grade As Double)
Select Case grade
    Case 0 To 59.99: letter = "F"
    Case 60 To 69.99: letter = "D"
    Case 70 To 79.99: letter = "C"
    Case 80 To 89.99: letter = "B"
    Case 90 To 100.99: letter = "A" ' assuming student can get a score over 100
End Select
get_letter = letter
End Function
```

Comment: This is working. Is there a better way to do the range change in the case statement? It just looks ugly to me.

Comment: There is Round() function which you can use on the scores before passing to the macro, where you can keep your original code, but depends on how you will define it... I mean, is 79.25 considered a B or C?  (I would say B if i'm a student)

Comment: Look at Gene's answer, it might be a better choice

Answer (score 1):

Or using `INDEX/MATCH`

```
Function get_letter(grade As Double) As String
get_letter = Evaluate("INDEX({""F"",""D"",""C"",""B"",""A""},MATCH(" & grade & ",{0,60,70,80,90,100}))")
End Function
```

*sample*

```
Sub b()
Debug.Print get_letter(59.99)
Debug.Print get_letter(60)
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you start at row 2:

```
Set grade = Range("J2")
Set letter = Range("K2")
```

and then immediately offset by 1 row in your loop:

```
Set grade = grade.Offset(1, 0)
Set letter = letter.Offset(1, 0)
```

therefore missing rows 1 to 2 out and starting at Row 3. Use the `x` variable in your loop to correct the problem:

```
For x = 1 To num_rows
    letter.Value = get_letter(grade.Value)
    Set grade = Range("J" & x)
    Set letter = Range("K" & x)
Next
```